# How add non model field to django filters

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I have a view with pagination and filtering that displays a list of products. I would like to provide the user with the option to choose between displaying all the products they can buy or displaying only the products they have already purchased.

**show_products.py**

```py
def show_products(previously_purchased, user):
    if previously_purchased:
        transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(user_id=user).values_list('product_id')
        return Product.objects.filter(pk__in=[q[0] for q in transactions])
    return Product.objects.all()
```

**models.py**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

**views.py**

```py
class ProductList(ListView):
    ...
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProductList, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_queryset(self):
        # show_ = True if 'previously_purchased' in  self.request.GET and self.request.GET['previously_purchased'] == 'True' else False
        self.filterset = ProductFilter(
            self.request.GET,
            queryset=show_products(previously_purchased=) # show_products(previously_purchased=show_)
        )
        return self.filterset.qs
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.filterset.form
        context['products'] = show_products(previously_purchased=)
        return context
```

**filters.py**

```py
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    CHOICE = {
        ('True', 'previously purchased'),
        ('False', 'all')
    }
    name = django_filters.CharFilter()
    # previously_purchased = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICE)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name']
```

The `show_products(previously_purchased=)` function is responsible for creating a queryset of all products or only previously purchased ones, using the `previously_purchased` parameter.

Unfortunately, when I add `previously_purchased` in `ProductFilter`, I get an error saying that the `previously_purchased` field does not exist in the `Product` model.

When I add `@property` in the `Product` model, and intercept `self.request.GET['previously_purchased']` to change the `show_products()` parameter, the display works fine. But the pagination stops working.

Comment: What does `show_products()` do.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I added before the Product List class definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [**`django-filter`**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) you can specify keyword argument named as [`method`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#method) inside field which accepts either a callable or the name of a method so you camodify you **`ProductFilter`** like this

```py
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    CHOICE = {
        ('True', 'previously purchased'),
        ('False', 'all')
    }
    name = django_filters.CharFilter()
    previously_purchased = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
                             choices=CHOICE,
                             method='filter_previously_purchased',
                           )
    def filter_previously_purchased(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value == 'True':
            transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user).values_list('product_id')
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=[q[0] for q in transactions])
        return queryset
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'previously_purchased',]
```

In above code I've added your `show_products()` logic inside `filter_previously_purchased` function with which takes these arguments

- **`queryset`** It is queryset of specified `model` eg. *`Product.objects.all()`*
- **`name`** it's a field name eg. `previously_purchased`
- **`value`** it's value which comes from client.